# How to access nested classes's data?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm learning C++ OOP and I met a problem with nested classes. 
I'm implementing a Notebook application which is formed from activities. 
In the `CActivity` class I have nested classes `CAdress` and `CDate`, which are friends with `CActivity`, so I should be able to access their data. However, when I'm creating a `CActivity` object, only `CActivity`'s data (`lchild`, `rchild` and `activity_name`) is accessible.

I want to access the `CDate` and `CAdress` for everytime I'm creating an `CActivity` object to save their data. `Notebook` class would represent a Binary Search Tree where activities are sorted by date.

Here I will provide the code:

```
class CActivity {
    friend class Notebook;
private:
     CActivity* lchild, * rchild;
     string activity_name;

     class CAdress
     {
         friend class CActivity;
     private:
         string city_name;
         int city_code;
         string street;
         int street_number;
     public:
         void setCity(string name) { this->city_name = name; }
         void setCityCode(int code) { this->city_code = code; }
         void setStreet(string str) { this->street = str; }
         void setNumber(int nr) { this->street_number = nr; }
         CAdress(string name, int code, string street, int nr)
         {
              setCity(name);
              setCityCode(code);
              setStreet(street);
              setNumber(nr);
         };

     };
     class CDate
     {
         friend class CActivity;
     private:
         int day;
         int month;
         int year;
     public:
         void setDay(int dd) { this->day = dd; }
         void setMonth(int mm) { this->month = mm; }
         void setYear(int yyyy) { this->year = yyyy; }
         CDate(int dd, int mm, int yyyy)
         {
             setDay(dd);
             setMonth(mm);
             setYear(yyyy);
         }; 

     };

public:
    CActivity(string activity){
        activity_name = activity;
        lchild = rchild = NULL;

    }
};
```

I don't really understand where's the problem... Please help with an advice. Thank you!

Comment: Well you don't have any instances of either `CAddress` or `CDate` anywhere.

Comment: Please take the time to create a [mcve] and post it. It's hard to formulate a sensible answer with code that does not show where the problem is.

Comment: [nested classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types) don't automatically get instantiated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you give me an example of how should i do that, please?

Comment: @lon how do you create an instance of CActivity?

Comment: @Ion Perhaps you could give an example of how you tried to access `CAddress` and `CData`? That might reveal where you should be  creating instances of those classes.

Comment: I've specified what I wanted to do, now.

Comment: There are no instances of those classes inside a `CActivity` instance.  A class defined inside another class is exactly like other classes, except for the access control and the scope of its name. (You might be confusing classes with objects.)

Comment: sorry for headache guys, i'm trying to learn :). Thank you very much!

Comment: You can reduce the amount of typing by renaming your member variables.  Use a prefix such as "m_" or maybe a suffix like "_".  You only need to use the `this->` syntax to differentiate parameters from members.

Comment: Your `CAdress` class should use an `initialization list` instead of internal *setters*.  The initialization occurs without having to call other functions (BTW, branching annoys processors and it causes them to pause, reflect and perform branch analysis instead of processing data instructions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested class CAdress, CData has no object! CActivity class should have access to CAddress, CData class. You can put CAddress or CData objects-member in CActivity to provide access to them. Should expose public access.

```
class CActivity {
    public : 
            CData m_cData;
            CAddress m_address;

....
```

}